# how to find largest value in an array without using any enumerables?

Tags: ruby

```
nums = [4, 6, 8, 7]
until num[index] == nil
    if num[index] > num[index + 1]
      puts num[index] 
      index += 1
    elsif
      index = index + 1
    end
```

For some reason, the output I get is:

8

Traceback (most recent call last):
1: from main.rb:21:in `<main>' main.rb:21:in` >': comparison of Integer with nil failed (ArgumentError)

Not sure how to fix the code to not get the ArgumentError.

Comment: You need another if to check if `nums[index + 1]` is not nil, otherwise, you get that error since you can't compare Integers with Nil objects.

Comment: Ok, I've been trying to implement another if statement like you said, but I'm still receiving the same error. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Of course `until nums[index] == nil; if nums[index + 1]; if nums[index] > nums[index + 1]; puts nums[index]; end; end; index += 1; end`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-sort) plus [`last`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-last):

```
[4, 6, 8, 7].sort.last # 8
```

both Array methods.

Answer (score 2):

We should of course keep the computational complexity to O(`nums.size`) (by making a single pass through the array). My friend @Sergio points out that there can be nothing simpler than

```
nums.max
  #=> 8
```

which uses the method [Array#max](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-max). This would also work well at [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Comment: nitpick: this starting value will fail you when `nums` is empty.

Comment: And if we can use `Array#max`, why not use it on `nums`? :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it'll return the largest in the array:

```
nums = [4, 6, 8, 7]
index=0
until index==nums.length-1  #
  if nums[index] > nums[index + 1]
    largest= nums[index] 
    index += 1
  else
    index = index + 1
  end
end
puts largest
```

Comment: I know. But I'm asking how to do it without enumerables.

Comment: Karen, what enumberable method are you referring to?

Comment: @Karen: `Array#max` is defined in `Array`, not in `Enumerable`.